# Can a GWT app be packaged as Appcelerator Titanium App?

Tags: gwt, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am curious regarding one answer from this question:

[Gwt: Run as desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319367/gwt-run-as-desktop-application)

Regarding packaging a GWT App into a Appcelerator Titanium app, is that really possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that GWT is written in Java but compiles down to HTML/CSS & JavaScript and is run thorough your browser. So you could easily put these HTML files in your Titanium app and use the web browser feature in the app to open them. So if you were on the iPad / iPhone it would open directly in a window in your app using safari.

- **But GWT isn't specific to any server side code, it's all client side so it will render in any browser. Should work just fine.**

Comment: thanks for the tip, yes it compiles into HTML/CSS & javascript however I am not sure how to "feed" this to the titanium design process as well as how the GWT side will access mobile API for the phone functions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would be unable to access the mobile phone functions from GWT.  Titanium doesn't really work that way, but I think PhoneGap is trying to setup their system to be able to interact with the mobile phone API through browser type of interaction.   Right now with Titanium Mobile I'm pretty sure your only option is to render that in a web view (Safari) and you wouldn't have access to the phone. You could still get GPS since you can request that in the browser, and use SQlite local storage (in the browse). But no camera or anything.

Comment: I dropped Titanium and just moved on to using PhoneGap instead, which I find better solution in my case.